# Crear una plantilla/master page en lenguaje php

Tags: php, html

Como puedo crear la estructura de una master/plantilla en **PHP** con alternativas diferentes al include y require independientemente del *contenido y el diseño*, gracias de antemano.

por ejemplo un menu que pueda ser visible en todos los ficheros y ahí mismo pueda hacer envio de datos por post:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a>lista</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Podrias explicarte mas detalladamente, tienes algo actualmente que puedas mostrarnos?

Comment: basicamente no es necesario mi contenido en este momento, ya que difiere un poco, pero supongamos que tengo un div>ul>li el cual quiero que se muestre como plantilla en todos mis documentos.

Comment: y si nos dices qué has investigado y en qué parte te has quedado? Somos StackOverflow en Español y ayudamos a resolver preguntas, sin embargo, dudo mucho que seamos un reemplazo para Google. Saludos

Comment: señor @fredyfx pedí ayuda acerca de "como crear una plantilla", lo que a "simple vista" se denota el escaso conocimiento que tengo del tema, no estoy pidiendo diseño de un sitio o que hagan el trabajo por mi, solo estoy pidiendo orientación y se ve claramente, y tampoco es necesario que me este insinuando que "busque en otro lado" de una manera "respetuosa".

Comment: a ver, vamos por partes, en primer lugar disculpa si te incomodé, en segundo lugar tienes más de 100 puntos que en lo personal considero que eres un usuario que 'conoce' cómo va el sitio, en tercer lugar, la pregunta es demasiado amplia pues hay muchas maneras de lograrlo, cuarto, para dejarme entender el motivo del comentario que redacté te invito a que leas un post desde mi teclado: http://fredyfx.com/saludos-nueva-generacion-de-programadores y finalmente, comparto la respuesta de @Dev.Joel: para iniciar está bien

Comment: por cierto, si deseas algo más avanzado, hay motores de plantillas para PHP: de este enlace: http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines te recomiendo Twig, que por diversos lares de la red, veo que tiene muchas buenas vistas, además es el que utiliza Drupal 8. Saludos.

Comment: no pasa nada, ya estoy abriendo las ligas, gracias por el aporte
saludos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**PHP** No tiene `masterPage` (Sin usar frameworks) sin embargo hay dos funciones para simular esto

[include()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) y [require()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require.php)

Creas dos archivos (o más) uno con nombre `header.php`  y otro `footer.php`

header.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>System</title>
  <!-- Styles -->
</head>
<body>
<header>

</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>
   <p> footer</p>
</footer>
```

y en tu página que deseas incluirlos sería

```
<?php 
  include 'header.php';/* Incluye el header ya creado */
   /* Contenido */
   <div id="main">

   </div>
  include 'footer.php'; /* Incluye el footer ya creado */

 ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, me parece interesante ya lo habia pensado de esa manera, pero creo que tendre algunas dificultades cuando quiera enviar por post los archivos incluidos en el principal.